# Keyboard AS3 detection

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener

I know there's a lot of questions on this but I'm really having troubles getting this to work.

I only have in the first frame this code:

```
var game = new Game(this);
```

In the game class I have a lot of stuff

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.events.*;




public class Game extends MovieClip {


    public function Game(esc) {
        var camp = new Camp(); //camp és l'escenari, el conjunt de celles
        var player = new Player();

        esc.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, controlTeclat);

        camp.mostraInterficie(esc);

        player.situaPlayer(esc);            

    }

    public function controlTeclat(ev){
        switch(ev.keyCode){
            /*case 37: player.moveLeft();break;
            case 38: player.moveUp();break;
            case 39: player.moveRight();break;
            case 40: player.moveDown();break;
            case 32: player.dropBomb();break;*/
        }
        trace ("hi");
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the controlaTeclat() function's never called, the trace is no printed. No error displayed, dough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mc will need to be on the displayList to receive keyboard events.

```
var game = new Game(this);
addChild( game );
```

Comment: beat me to it.  +1 as this is a must.

Comment: I added this to the first frame but still won't work. Thanks for your quik answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more code it's hard to say exactly what's going wrong here, however if the esc object doesn't have focus (hasn't been clicked by the mouse) then keyboard events won't propagate through it and so the handler won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the keyboard listener to the stage itself. You can also set the focus with 'stage.focus' so it will receive events without having to click on the stage first.

```
stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyupHandler );

//if you want to, you can set focus like this:   
stage.focus = stage; //or some other object


private function keyupHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    trace("keyupHandler()");
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works if i put it on the first frame but I've got a restriction from my teacher that sais I can't program on the frames. 

Now in the first frame I have this and it does not work. How can I put this in the class game (I pass the stage from the first frame) and make it work?

Thanks

Comment: @MarcGuilera I realize you're probably busy being in school and whatnot but on stackoverflow you should generally either be accepting someone else's answer (whatever helped you most) or writing up a more complete answer if you have the time to explain what went wrong and how you resolved (then accept your own).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (esc.stage) esc.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, controlTeclat);
else trace("Stage is inaccessible!");
```

The best practice is allocating your keyboard listeners to stage, so that they will always react to keyboard events. "esc" is your Document class seemingly, but it's not the stage, so we use "stage" property of "esc" to get access there.